# MacOS creating SFS (Self-certifying File System) group

Tags: macos, filesystems

Attempting to run the SFS file system toolkit (http://www.fs.net/). As I executed `./configure`, an error shows with message
`configure: error: Create sfs user/group or use --with-sfsuser/--with-sfsgroup`
I have correctly appended a group and password in `/etc/group` and `/etc/passwd`, as per the instruction:

```
echo "sfs:*:7878:7878::0:0:SFS User:/Users/sfs:/bin/false" | sudo niload -p passwd /

echo "sfs:*:7878:" | sudo niload -p group /
```

where I manually modified those files since `niload` command is outdated.

I did some searching and found MacOS doesn't use `/etc/group` and `/etc/passwd`. So then I used `dseditgroup` to create a group named "sfs:*:7878:", still, doesn't work. Here what is confusing me is the difference between an "SFS group" as described in the instruction and a normal "group", and the point of 7878 (which I guess would be some port?) used in the command, but no more definition or explanation can be found on the website.

Executing `./configure` with `--with-sfsgroup` parameter only causes the program to crash earlier. Somebody has an idea on what might be happening?